# Direction to another view from View Model

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am filtering  a list in a view model, but after that is done i need to be redirected to another page with the data. 
This is how i am doing it at the moment, but the page has no navigation bar even though i have set it to true in xaml and once i press one item i get an error 
My error
    System.InvalidOperationException: 'PushAsync is not supported globally on Android, please use a NavigationPage.'

My filter View Model

```
     bool _filterAllItems;
            public bool FilterAllItems
            {
                set
                {
                    _filterAllItems = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();

                    if (_filterAllItems)
                    {
                        _parentCategoryId = -1;
                        FillArticles();
                         Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new ArticlesForPurchaseFiltered());


                    }

                }
                get => _filterAllItems;
            }


this is how i am selecting the item in the content page




 private async void ListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
            {
    #if !NAVIGATION
                var selectedItem = ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem;
                var articlePage = new MyArticle(selectedItem as ArticleDetailData);

                await Navigation.PushAsync(articlePage);
    #endif

        }

Can you please suggest how to redirect to View page from View model so i dont use 
 Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new ArticlesForPurchaseFiltered());
```

Comment: Did you define the MainPage as a  NavigationPage  `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());` ?

Comment: MainPage = GetMainPage();
        }

        public static Page GetMainPage()
{
            return new RootMasterDetailPage();
          }

Comment: MainPage = new NavigationPage(GetMainPage()); i have tried this and still doenst work. I get the same error

Comment: Does it work when you invoke the line in content page ?

Comment: Sorry can you be more specific

Comment: My navigation works normally, i dont have an issue. I just think that Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new ArticlesForPurchaseFiltered()); is not correct. I dont even have a Navigation bar on the page even thought is set to true

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:**

We could not invoke the method `PushModalAsync` in MasterDetailPage . It would be better call it in the specific ContentPage .

**Solution:**

We could use **MessagingCenter** to send notification .

#### in ViewModel

```
 _parentCategoryId = -1;
 FillArticles();

MessagingCenter.Send<Object>(this,"Push");
```

#### in the constructor of the ContentPage (which contains the listview)

```
public xxxPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();


    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object>(this, "Push", (args) => { 

       // Navigation.PushAsync(articlePage);

   });
}
```

**Solution2 :**

You could pass the Page as parameter to ViewModel .

```
private ContentPage currentPage;

public FilterArticlesForPurchaseViewModel(ContentPage page)
{
    currentPage = page ;
}
```

```
currentPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new ArticlesForPurchaseFiltered());
```

#### And in ContentPage

```
BindingContext = new FilterArticlesForPurchaseViewModel(this);
```

Comment: I have tried this but  _parentCategoryId = -1;
                    FillArticles();
                    MessagingCenter.Send<Object>(this, "Push"); doesnt give me any action

Comment: public ArticlesForPurchaseFiltered() 
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new FilterArticlesForPurchaseViewModel();
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object>(this, "Push", (args) => {
            });


        //}

//        private async void ListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {

            var selectedItem = ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem;
            var articlePage = new MyArticle(selectedItem as ArticleDetailData);
            await Navigation.PushAsync(articlePage);
    //    }

Comment: Add the code in {} .It will be invoked when the value changed in VM .

Comment: MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object>(this, "Push", (args) => {
                var articlePage = new MyArticle(args as ArticleDetailData);
                Navigation.PushAsync(articlePage);
            });
like this?

Comment: Or you could check the second solution .

Comment: Updated answer still gives me the same problem. If i change it selection of the item to PushModal then it works, but i am still not getting Navigation bar which is a massive issue.

Comment: Could you share your sample so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: its part of  a big project it would take a while

Comment: You could create a new project and use the part code to reproduce the issue .

Comment: I have decided to implmenet a buton that would redirect me after selecting a check box and then use Command, that will work i hope